# How to design post api which accepts JSON Array as input in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, validation, http-post

Input json

[{"customerId":"1","customerName":"a"},
{"customerId":"2","customerName":"b"}]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the request in the appropriate manner for the parameter --

.

1. The signature of the method can be --

```
postCustomers(Customers customers)
```

.

2. The `Customers` can be defined as --

```
public class Customers {
    @JsonProperty("customers")
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

.

3. The individual `Customer` can be modeled based on the required attributes --

```
public class Customer {
    @JsonProperty("customerId")
    private String customerId;

    @JsonProperty("customerName")
    private String customerName;
}
```